# Is there a way to access the properties of pages in confluence from inside a custom macro?

Tags: confluence

I want to check the names of the labels in the page on which the macro is enabled and its children as well. Is this possible using a custom macro? I followed this tutorial: 
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/create-a-confluence-hello-world-macro/

And looked at some other documentation but couldn't verify.

Answer (score 1):

The [Page](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/6.6.0/index.html?com/atlassian/confluence/pages/Page.html) class gives you access to both the page's labels (via `getLabels()`) and ALL the page's children (via `getChildren()`, but note *no* permission checking is done). I don't have a Java dev environment right now, but I was able to display the labels for the current page and its children in a user macro (via the `$content` variable):

```
<h2>Labels</h2>
<code>$content.labels</code>
<h2>Children's Labels</h2>
<ul>
#foreach($child in $content.children)
    <li> <code> $child.labels </code> </li>
#end
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of -

1) Custom Plugin

I am covering high-level detail of how to get the desired result. You may face a couple of errors when actually trying to do this. So GOOGLE is your best friend.

- First, you will have to retrieve all the pages with you macro on it with SQL query

  ```
  SELECT c.contentid, c.contenttype, c.title, s.spacekey
   FROM CONTENT c
  JOIN BODYCONTENT bc
  ON c.contentid = bc.contentid
  JOIN SPACES s
  ON c.spaceid = s.spaceid
  WHERE c.prevver IS NULL
  AND c.contenttype IN ('PAGE', 'BLOGPOST')
  AND bc.body LIKE '%ac:name="<macro_name>"%';
  ```
- Then get all the pages with the label using something like :

  `SELECT * FROM CONTENT 
    WHERE CONTENTID IN (SELECT CONTENTID FROM CONTENT_LABEL 
                  WHERE LABELID IN (SELECT LABELID FROM LABEL 
                      WHERE NAME='<label name>'));`
- Join result of both of them together using content Id or you could also make one call to get already joined output.
- You have the pages.
- You can get their children using another query like

  `SELECT c.contentid, c.title FROM CONFANCESTORS a JOIN CONTENT c ON a.descendentid = c.contentid WHERE a.ancestorid = '<parent_page_id>'`

2) Rest Calls

It is a little complicated way, I wouldn't recommend but the steps would similar to custom plugin.